# Android change "up" button image

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I am creating an Android application with **custom navigation bar**.

My current navigation bar looks like this:

[image]

I would like to create a navigation bar like this:

[image]

To create a navigation bar like this, at first I need to change default Android "up" button. To achieve this In developers forums I have found a way:

```
<style name="MyCustomTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="android:homeAsUpIndicator">@drawable/custom_up_button</item>
</style>
```

And set this theme in `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<activity
        android:name=".LoginActivity"
        android:theme="@style/MyCustomTheme"
        android:label="LOGIN" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.mycompany.HomeActivity" />

    </activity>
```

Sadly, this doesn't change my "up" button. I must be doing something wrong. Does anyone know what?

Comment: Why would you change an Android specific UI to an iOS one?

Comment: Because a client asks for it... Anyway, there should be a way to do that...

Comment: But are you setting this theme to your app in the manifest file?

Comment: `<activity`
            `android:name=".LoginActivity"`
            `android:theme="@style/AppTheme"` so I guess so...

Comment: Your AppTheme uses a parent which should not have an actionBar is that intended too?

Comment: No it wasn't. Sorry, Im new in Android programming...

Comment: I have updated question, please take a look at it

Answer (score 1):

You can change it programmatically like this:

-Add your drawable into the folder
-Create an object Action bar and change it like this:

`ActionBar ab = getSupportActionBar();
ab.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
ab.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
ab.setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.yourDrawable);`

and it works.

Answer (score 0):

Change it programmatically with:

```
Drawable upArrow = ContextCompat.getDrawable(getApplicationContext(), R.drawable.custom_up_button);
getSupportActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator(upArrow);
```

Comment: Is there a method to make it with XML? Also method `getDrawable` is deprecated...

Comment: I've update sorry for getDrawable I wrote it quickly @TomKortney